# Adding button to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to customize DataGridView class to have a button beneath all rows.

So far I've added a button to a DataGridView.Controls.

The position of this button is calculated on each add/remove row, DataGridView resize and scroll.

This works, however there is a one problem with that. On DataGridView resize or scroll, when bottom edge of the DataGridView is directly below last row, the button is not visible at all or just partially.

Is there a way to make the button always visible?

I've tried setting scrollbar position and FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex. This does not work.
Unfortunatelly adding a whole new row isn't possible for this project.

[image: button partially visible]

Adding button:

```
buttonAddRow.Height = 17;
buttonAddRow.Text = "+";
buttonAddRow.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.System;
buttonAddRow.Font = new Font(buttonAddRow.Font.FontFamily, 6.75F);
buttonAddRow.Click += ButtonAddRow_Click;
dataGridView.Controls.Add(buttonAddRow);
```

And the location:

```
private void setLocation()
{
    if (dataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell != null)
    {
        int positionY = 0;
        positionY += dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight;

        var visibleRowsCount = dataGridView.DisplayedRowCount(true);
        var firstDisplayedRowIndex = dataGridView.FirstDisplayedCell.RowIndex;
        var lastvisibleRowIndex = (firstDisplayedRowIndex + visibleRowsCount) - 1;
        for (int rowIndex = firstDisplayedRowIndex; rowIndex <= lastvisibleRowIndex; rowIndex++)
        {
            positionY += dataGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Height;
        }

        buttonAddRow.Location = new Point(dataGridView.ClientRectangle.X, dataGridView.ClientRectangle.Y + positionY);
        buttonAddRow.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: button has to be under last grid row or at the bottom of grid?

Comment: Won't you have to make the DataDridView a bit taller?

Comment: Well, how could you display the button benath the last row??? this doesn't seem logical if your dgv is filled with rows.. Possible workaround: Make the last row twice the normal height..

Comment: @Ash - under the last grid row. If there are only few rows so that, the vertical scroll isn't visible and the last row is e.g. in the middle of the grid, the button will be also in the middle of the grid.

Comment: @stuartd - if I make the grid taller, next FirstDisplayedRow row, which wasn't displayed, will be displayed and the button goes also down. This would work, if I could increase the space between DataGridView bottom edge and the last row. Unfortunatelly I didn't find the way how to do this.

Comment: @TaW - no, I am not allowed to make it higher.

Comment: Do you know how to a) decide if the scrollbar is visible and b) its height?

Comment: Yes, i know it.

Comment: To keep the rows from being partially covered up at the bottom of the `DataGridView`s bounding box, have you tried setting the `DataGridView`s  `AutoSizeRowsMode` to `AllCells`?

Comment: This requirement seems very odd. The supplied code will put the button into the grid at the last row IF the rows do not extend past the bottom bounds of the `DataGridView`. If the rows extend past the bounding box of the `DataGridView` then the button will not be added to the `DataGridView` because the variable `positionY` will be outside the bounding box of the `DataGridView`. Without knowing WHAT this button is used for it appears that a button OUTSIDE the `DataGridView` would not only be easier but would seem more logical depending on what the button is used for

Comment: @JohnG Yes, your right. The button should not be always visible. It should be visible only if last row is visible. The functionality of the button is to add a new row. It should work similar to this https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument778

Comment: Unfortunately, as a posted on the beginning, I am not allowed to add whole new row. The reason for that is, that there is a lot of logic in the existing dgv which loops through all of the rows. If I add new row(which would properly show this additional row) I had to check all of the places where row count is used.

Comment: @JohnG Unfortunatelly setting AutoSizeRowsMode to AllCells doesn't work.

Comment: The link you posted is describing a feature of a DevExpress `DataGrid` and the `DataGridView` does not provide this property that I am aware of. You will most likely have to implement this feature yourself. If the functionality of the button is to add a new row then I am confused by your comment _”I am not allowed to add whole new row”_…… regardless of the necessary logic, if you are not allowed to add a “whole” new row then I am confused as to what this “add new row” button would do.

Comment: "You will most likely have to implement this feature yourself." - yes that's, why I've added the button. I wasn't precise enough. I am not allowed to add this one special "add new row" row. Other types of rows which are already covered by the logic I can add of course. Would it be possible to set scrolling somehow to scroll more then to the last row, so that the last row is further above the bottom dgv edge?

Comment: Because the button is not part of the rows in the `DataGridView`, you will have to keep track of this button. If there are more rows than will fit in the grid, I am curious WHERE you would put this button. Example, if there were a thousand rows and the grid only had room to display 20 of those rows at a time and the user has scrolled the grid such that there are additional rows not displayed above the grid and additional rows not displayed below. In this situation, WHERE would you put this button?

Comment: My question would be WHY is this necessary? If the button is going to be used to add new rows, then a button OUTSIDE the `DataGridView` would seem far more logical and would be available to the user no matter where the rows are positioned in the grid and relieving you of having to implement this button INSIDE the grid.

Comment: If you must have this button row inside the grid, I would recommend you make a “Button ROW” and insert/delete this row as the user scrolls through the rows. This will most likely involve implementing the OnPaint method if the button row is to extend through all the columns. In Addition, if you must add the button inside the grid it may be easier to wrap the `DataGridView` into your own `MyDataGridView` that has this feature. This seems like a lot of work to simply add a row to the grid.

Answer (score 0):

Below is some code that creates a “button Row” I described earlier and adds this button row to the top, bottom and row 4 of the `DataGridView`. As the picture shows this button is only in the first column. If you want to display the button across all columns then you will have to implement the OnPaint method to adjust this row. However, looking at the picture, if the user scrolls down then the top button row will not be visible, this is where you would have to implement keeping the button row at the top as the user scrolled down. If this is what you are looking for, then what you end up with is a STATIC button that is always displayed at the top of the grid. Again putting this button ABOVE and OUTSIDE the grid would accomplish the same thing, with much less effort.

[image]

The code below uses a `DataGridView` with 3 text columns.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  FillGrid();
  InsertButtonRow(0);
  InsertButtonRow(4);
  InsertButtonRow(dataGridView.Rows.Count -1);
}

private void FillGrid() {
  for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++) {
    dataGridView.Rows.Add("Row" + i + "C1", "Row" + i + "C2", "Row" + i + "C3");
  }
}

private void InsertButtonRow(int rowIndex) {
  if (rowIndex >= 0 && rowIndex < dataGridView.Rows.Count) {
    DataGridViewButtonCell buttonCell = new DataGridViewButtonCell();
    buttonCell.Value = "+";
    buttonCell.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells[0] = buttonCell;
    dataGridView.Rows.Insert(rowIndex, row);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JohnG. Thank you very much for your example. Yes, I was aware of putting the button in a cell. But this is again the same problem that I wanted to avoid - adding a new extra row. If I would want to place the button beneath last row, I would need to add extra row without cell borders and put a button in a cell. In this case I would need to check all the logic which loops through the rows. If the button is added to dgv.Controls, the rows stays intact and no logic must be checked. Anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: Looking at the devexpress example in the link, the grid appears to have this feature, where you can place the “new item row” either at the top OR the bottom of the visible portion of the grid. It clearly appears to be some kind of “inserted” row. I guess the main point I am trying to make is this… if the grid is filled with rows… WHERE could you possibly add this button without covering up something? The example in the link appears to use rows. Even when the new row is at the top, it may “appear” as a button, but I am guessing behind the scenes… it’s a row.